# How to add tag on condition with ternary operator in pug?

Tags: pug

This works ok

```
li.li
   if rout === '/about'
      | about
   else
      a(href='/about') about
```

Is there a way to write it in one line? Something like this

```
li.li=(rout === '/about') ? 'about' : (a(href='/about') about)
```

Comment: No, pug doesn't output new elements as the product of an element's tag.

Comment: 4 lines for conditional tag is a bit an overkill :(

Comment: There is a difference between a DOM element and a DOM element's tag.  You aren't looking to output a conditional tag, you want to output a conditional element.

Comment: @Graham The two seem synonymous in this context. I don't see the distinction

Comment: tag = element's property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it would work, this...

```
li.li=(rout === '/about') ? 'about' : (a(href='/about') about)
```

...is messy. Better approach is to use mixin.

#### SchrodingerLink mixin

When `link` === `url`, mixin returns *verbose name*. In all other cases it will wrap *verbose name* in link.

```
mixin schrodingerLink(link, verboseName)

   if url === link
      | #{verboseName}
   else
      a.a(href=link)= verboseName
```

Usage:

```
li.li
   +schrodingerLink('/about', 'О проекте')
```

(Compare with non-mixin usage:

```
li.li
   if url === '/about'
      | О проекте
   else
      a.a(href='/about') О проекте
```

)